# How can I debug IOZONE over the network?

Tags: networking, ssh, performance, io

I'm working on a mac and I have a vm running ubuntu server.

I created a file `vm_client.iozone` that looks like:

```
vm /path/to/test /usr/bin/iozone
```

I have configured iozone to work over ssh using `export RSH=ssh`.

When running the test: `iozone -+m vm_client.iozone -i 0 -+t`,
I get valid network test results:

```
vm received 512 kBytes @   26200.01 kBytes/sec
```

etc.

I'm starting iozone without the net test using this cmd: `iozone -+m vm_client.iozone -i 0`.

And I get this output:
    Iozone: Performance Test of File I/O
            Version $Revision: 3.428 $
        Compiled for 64 bit mode.
        Build: macosx

```
Contributors:William Norcott, Don Capps, Isom Crawford, Kirby Collins
             Al Slater, Scott Rhine, Mike Wisner, Ken Goss
             Steve Landherr, Brad Smith, Mark Kelly, Dr. Alain CYR,
             Randy Dunlap, Mark Montague, Dan Million, Gavin Brebner,
             Jean-Marc Zucconi, Jeff Blomberg, Benny Halevy, Dave Boone,
             Erik Habbinga, Kris Strecker, Walter Wong, Joshua Root,
             Fabrice Bacchella, Zhenghua Xue, Qin Li, Darren Sawyer,
             Vangel Bojaxhi, Ben England, Vikentsi Lapa.

Run began: Mon Oct 13 10:55:33 2014

Network distribution mode enabled.
Command line used: iozone -+m vm_client.iozone -i 0
Output is in kBytes/sec
Time Resolution = 0.000001 seconds.
Processor cache size set to 1024 kBytes.
Processor cache line size set to 32 bytes.
File stride size set to 17 * record size.
                                                          random    random     bkwd    record    stride
          kB  reclen    write  rewrite    read    reread    read     write     read   rewrite      read   fwrite frewrite    fread  freread
         512       4  1118011  3659616

iozone test complete.
```

But i'm quite certain it didn't run anything on the remote host specified in the `vm_client.iozone` file as I don't see any connections (running sshd -d on the client).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing iozone's sources I have figured it out.

I managed to make IOZONE start the ssh sessions and run: add the `-t <num of clients in file that was given with -+m>`.

For example:
    iozone -+m vm_client.iozone -i 0 -t 1

It enters 'throughput mode' and the number of processes that are specified must match the number of clients (process for each client in the .cfg given with -+m).

Isn't documented on any of the official IOZONE manuals.